# NPM/NVM error when starting tmux: nvm is not compatible with the npm config "prefix" option: currently set to ""

Tags: npm, tmux, nvm

When I start a new tmux sessions with `tmux`, `tmux new` or `tmux new-session`, I get the following error:

```
module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '../lib/utils/unsupported.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:19:21
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:153:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
nvm is not compatible with the npm config "prefix" option: currently set to ""
Run `npm config delete prefix` or `nvm use --delete-prefix v10.8.0 --silent` to unset it.
```

I have tried the solution for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34718528/nvm-is-not-compatible-with-the-npm-config-prefix-option) i.e. `npm delete prefix` but to no avail: running outside the tmux session doesn't fix the problem, and running within the tmux session throws the top section of the previous error again (without the npm warning):

```
module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '../lib/utils/unsupported.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:19:21
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:153:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
```

This appears to be an issue with npm somehow as the .js error also occurs when I run `npm --help`. However, this only occurs within tmux.

Any solutions?

Comment: I have also discovered this problem only on MacOS. Works fine on Linux. Also npm and node work fine for me even on MacOS (I don't get the JS error you do), but as soon as the shell starts I get the `nvm is not compatible with...` message. It's also running a system version of node, and I can use a different version with nvm. But curious why this only happens with tmux

Answer (score 2):

After digging on the internet I found some accepted answers:

Try config the $NVM_DIR reference again.

For example nvm use v7.10.0, and have the error: Run `npm config delete prefix` or `nvm use --delete-prefix v7.10.0 --silent` to unset it.

You need overwrite nvm prefix,

npm config set prefix $NVM_DIR/versions/node/v7.10.0

https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/855#issuecomment-314309706

**OR**

If you're using any other shell than bash, make sure to configure your tmux that way:

```
# set default shell to zsh
set -g default-command /bin/zsh
set -g default-shell /bin/zsh
```

This solved it for me.

https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/1245#issuecomment-370396741

**OR**

comment out the code below in your shell file (such as ~/.zshrc):

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

log out your account and log in

uncommnet these code above and source shell file

**OR**

```
nvm unalias default
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47861348/6700273
https://blog.natetodd.com/nvm/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but none of these work. Were you able to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should run

> npm install

this should do the trick.

Comment: Sorry that doesn't work for me. This appears as soon as the shell starts. Were you able to reproduce the error with `nvm`?

Answer (score 0):

> Fixed: it looks like this might be specific to how macOS handles
>   pathes on each bash shell. Adding the recommended path-clearing logic
>   to my profile files fixed this issue for me.

Seeing this too, just on tmux, with nvm installed via the curl script.

Oddly, it seems like I'm using different versions of npm when in tmux and when I'm just in my shell (zsh). When I'm in tmux, doing a which npm results in `/usr/local/bin/npm` while in zsh, it's `/Users/brett/.nvm/versions/node/v10.8.0/bin/npm`.

It seems like it might be related to tmux reloading my profile files, and appending more paths to $PATH.

**Look here:** [When using tmux nvm isn't being sourced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47442647/when-using-tmux-nvm-isnt-being-sourced?rq=1)

Comment: Don't have node installed through brew. This question pertains to [nvm (Node Version Manager)](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm).

Comment: @JeffPuckett   Did you checked it?  There is no specific solution

Comment: Sorry none of those solutions work for me. Were you able to reproduce it?

Comment: Is it problem only on 'Mac' ?

Comment: It works fine on Mac. Only happens inside tmux on Mac.

Comment: Look at my answer now. I have not recreated this. I am looking for forums. People have a similar problem, different solutions. In some works, not in others.

Comment: @JeffPuckett Did you try?

Answer (score 0):

Bash starts as a login shell in tmux. On macOS it is ~/.bash_profile, not ~/.bashrc that is sourced then, AFAIK.

Have you tried adding `source ~/.bashrc` to your ~/.bash_profile?

Comment: yes both are being sourced. same issue. were you able to reproduce the original error?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another possible solution:

```
$ npm config delete prefix 
$ npm config set prefix $NVM_DIR/versions/node/v6.11.1
```

This should delete and reset the prefix, which you can edit later.

Comment: I hope that this will help!

Comment: Thanks, but if you read the original posted question, you should see that this was already tried and doesn't work here.

Comment: You could look at this link (the second answer, the one with 55 upvotes): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34718528/nvm-is-not-compatible-with-the-npm-config-prefix-option

Comment: Then I have no idea how to solve this problem, sorry!